# How to preserve the order of elements after Scala Split()

Tags: apache, scala

I have a string like this:

```
myString = "Name:varchar nullable  ,Age:varchar nullable,BirthTimestamp:varchar nullable,Time:varchar nullable,ZipCode:varchar nullable,Address:varchar nullable"
```

I'm trying to parse this string like this-->

```
val tmp = myString.split(",").map(x=>x.split(":")).map(x=>
  x(0)->x(1).split(" ")).toMap
tmp.foreach(x=>println(x._1+" "+x._2.foreach(y=>print(y))))
```

This is printed as

```
varcharnullableName ()
varcharnullableAddress ()  --> Why Address is printed here instead of Map? 
varcharnullableBirthTimestamp ()
varcharnullableAge ()
varcharnullableZipCode ()
varcharnullableTime ()
```

How do I preserve the order of these elements similar to the input String?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `Map` is unordered, simply remove the `.toMap` and it works:

```
val tmp = myString.split(",").map(x=>x.split(":")).map(x=>
  x(0)->x(1).split(" "))
```